# Compare "nslookup host" to "nslookup ip"

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, dns, nslookup

I am in need to determine if DNS lookup by host matches the output of DNS lookup by IP on the Windows platform using standard windows tools (CMD, VBS, POWERSHELL).

Here is an example -

1. Query the hostname (haw1) using NSLOOKUP

   ```
   C:>nslookup haw1
   Server:  myserver.blah.org
   Address:  172.22.14.10

   Name:    haw1.blah.org
   Address:  172.40.82.70
   ```
2. Then query the IP address from the result in #1

   ```
   C:>nslookup 172.40.82.70
   Server:  myserver.blah.org
   Address:  172.22.14.10

   Name:    ghi1.blah.org
   Address:  172.40.82.70
   ```
3. Compare the results to see if they match. In this example
   haw1.blah.org <> ghi.blah.org
4. Output something like "haw1.blah.org does not match" or
   "haw1.blah.org matches" depending on the results.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Adding what I have so far...

This leaves me with the FQDN of the item and the IP the name returns from DNS.  I am at a loss how to then proceed to do the reverse DNS lookup and the comparison.

What I have is only a partial solution.

```
if exist name.txt del name.txt
if exist address.txt del address.txt
nslookup %1 > out.txt
type out.txt | find /v /i "server" >out1.txt
del out.txt
type out1.txt | find /v /i "172.22.14.10" >out.txt
del out1.txt
type out.txt | find /i "name" > name.txt
type out.txt | find /i "address:" > address.txt
del out.txt
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in (name.txt) do echo %%i >name1.txt
del name.txt
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in (address.txt) do echo %%i >address1.txt
del address.txt
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *Then query the IP address* - what makes you think there will only be one IP address? Or there won't be any CNAMEs? Or there will only be one PTR entry? Use `Resolve-DnsName`, but downvote for reason "this question doesn't show any research effort"

Comment: Often times a device shows in DNS that no longer exists and a new device is assigned the same IP.  I am trying to determine if this is occurring:

    NSLOOKUP comp1  returns 172.10.10.10      reverse lookup NSLOOKUP 172.10.10.10  returns comp2.   Verified NSLOOKUP comp2  ->  172.10.10.10  (sorry I can't figure out how to do code in a comment)

I'm not the DNS guy, but I have to do this by hand all day long and trying to automate it.

Comment: Resolve-DnsName is not valid for Windows 7 so this is not an answer that would work on any supported Windows version

Comment: That problem is automatically solved by [DNS aging and scavenging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771677%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TessellingHeckler pointed out, there are many cases where this approach will fail. With that said here is a PowerShell method using the `Net.DNS` from .Net that should be usable on Windows 7:

```
$ComputerName = "haw1"
$NameLookup = [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($ComputerName)
$IPAddress = @($NameLookup.AddressList)[0].IPAddressToString
$IPLookup = [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($IPAddress)
$NameLookup.HostName -eq $IPLookup.HostName
```

Answer (score 1):

This example will ask for you to type or paste a remote computer name and report whether there is an IP mismatch or not.

```
Clear-Host 
$ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt "IP Mismatch? Type or Paste a computer name here to detect >"

$NameLookup = [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($ComputerName)
$IPAddress = @($NameLookup.AddressList)[0].IPAddressToString
$IPLookup = [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($IPAddress)

$_N = $NameLookup.HostName.ToString()
$_NIP = $NameLookup.AddressList.IPAddressToString
$_R = $IPLookup.HostName.ToString()
$_RIP = $IPLookup.AddressList.IPAddressToString
If ($_N -eq $_R ) {

    Write-Host "NO MISMATCH!`n$_N,$_NIP`n$_R,$_RIP"

}
Else {

    Write-Host "WARNING MISMATCH!`n$_N,$_NIP`n$_R,$_RIP"

}

#Original Source from
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655065/compare-nslookup-host-to-nslookup-ip
#Modified by John Delise 2022-01-01 Happy New Year
```